# Google Calendar Title Set to Display None

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, google-calendar-api

We have a google calendar in our [store site](https://motorhelmets.com/pages/calendar) and we want to set the title style to "display: none".

Here's our code so far:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('iframe').contents().find('span').css('display', 'none');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you open your console by doing to inspect element (F12) and going to the console tab, you can see the error you face:

"jquery-2.1.4.min.js?1013665…:2 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://motorhelmets.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://calendar.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Google domain doesn't allow editing form external domains.

However since the content you want to hide is at the edge of the frame (ie at the top), there a couple of tricks you could use with css to hide it. For instance you raise the iframe content or the iframe itself could be moved higher hence covering up the title or you could use some html element to cover up the title.

The following is the html code to cover up the title. It needs to be inserted inside the *calendar_iframe* div right before the iframe.

`<div style="position: absolute;height: 20px;width: 100%;background: white;"></div>`

Comment: wow. now i know ! :D you enlightened me :) thanks
btw, do you have any suggestions how to hide this ? or there's now way to hide this calendartitle ? :(

Comment: I just noticed the data you want to remove at the top. I have updated the solution in the answer... I have already tested it on the website.

Comment: thank you so much for your time  sir =) it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the link in Google Calender. You can also just add to the GET parameters.

&showTitle=0

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div just above the calendar iframe

```
<div id="hide-calendar-title"></div>
<iframe...>
```

Then apply this css to the div

```
#hide-calendar-title {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}
```